# GWT compiler errors in Ant buildfile

Tags: java, gwt, ant, gwt-compiler

I have the following Ant target:

```
<target name="gwtc" depends="main-compile">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
        <classpath refid="gwtc.path"/>

        <!-- Provision GWT Compiler with necessary memory. -->
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>

        <!-- Command-line arguments to the GWT Compiler. -->
        <!-- Log everything for debugging & auditing purposes. -->
        <arg line="-logLevel"/>
        <arg value="ALL"/>

        <!-- Maximize JavaScript optimization (range is [0,9]). -->
        <arg line="-optimize"/>
        <arg value="9"/>

        <!-- Generate a Story of Your Compile (SOYC) report for auditing purposes. -->
        <arg line="-compileReport"/>

        <!-- Specify the GWT Modules to compile -->
        <arg line="${src.dir}/com/myapp/WebModule"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

When I run this from the Ant command line I get the following error:

```
gwtc:
    [java] Checking for updates
    [java] [ERROR] Invalid module name: 'src/com/myapp/WebModule'
    [java]    First launch was 13ac843ee4b

BUILD FAILED
/home/myuser/sandbox/workbench/eclipse/workspace/myapp/build/targets.xml:243: Java returned: 1
```

And actually, there are several GWT modules I'd like to pass to the GWT compiler, not just `WebModule`. How do I tweak the Ant XML to give the GWT compiler what it's looking for? Preferably, there'd be a way to specify all the modules inside the `com.myapp` package, and then pass that as the parameter. That way, every time I add a module I don't need to remember to go back and change the build XML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `/src` at the end of your ant property `gwtc.path`.

Comment: Thanks @rsp but then I get a failed build for: `Reference gwtc.path/src not found`.

Comment: I meant to add it to the value of that property that should be declared elsewhere in the buildfile or passed on the commandline maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the *module name* to the compiler, not a file path. I.e. `com.myapp.WebModule`. The `${src.dir}` has to be in the classpath for the compiler so it can find the module and the Java source files.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading GWT from http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/list, extract the content from zip folder. Please refer the build scripts "build.xml" provided by GWT team in "sample" folder projects like "Hello" .

For multi-module projects in GWT. 
Refer - http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/tips-on-organizing-gwt-modules/

---

Also, the dev compiler takes only one "final" main module.